# Application Insights contains a lot of request traces

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, azure-application-insights

I'm doing a review of some Identity Server 4 applications that uses Serilog and writes to application insights. All of them have a lot of telemetry that are traces with information about the request. I can't find anything in the code that add these traces.
Are these built in traces in Identity Server 4 or any other part, and can one disable them?

[image: Application Insights telemetry]

Comment: It doesn't seem like default traces of a .net core app. Might be a serilog thing

Comment: I found now that it is only the applications that were using Identity Server 4 that have these traces.  Need to figure out how to disable those.

Comment: Can you post the related configuration about the logging? Perhaps, you are configuring the application for logging each of the Http Request. Or perhaps the issue is related the logging level.

Comment: It's also possible to filter them out using TelemetryProcessor

Answer (score 0):

We usually use [telemetry processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c) to filter out the unwanted telemetry data.

You can write a custom telemetry processor to handle this issue. The key is that you should find a property or properties combination to identify the data is coming from identityserver4, then use them to filter out the unwanted data.

Comment: Yes, I have telemetry processors for filtering out unwanted telemetry data. In this case I would like to avoid it if it's possible since I believe Identity Server is responsible for those and a better solution would be to disable them. But it it's not possible, we need to use the telemetry approach.

Comment: @Lillvik, yes, it's better if the Identity server can handle this. But if it's not, we should use telemetry approach. And if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks:).